# Is there a way to keep the selection in Windows 2008 Explorer when changing the sort order

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-server-2008, sorting, selection

A nice *feature* of Windows Explorer up to Windows Server 2003 at least (I don't have easy access to Vista or Windows 7 to know when this was lost) was that you could select multiple files (or folders) and then change the sort order by clicking on the column name and the files would reorder (unless you have thousands of files) but the existing selections do *not* change.

Can an equivalent (or better?) functionality be perfomed with Windows Server 2008?

Comment: Same in Win7, not sure about Vista

Comment: @Basiclife: Same in which way? You can or can't reorder and keep existing selections?

Comment: Sorting in Win7 clears the selection. I haven't found a way to preserve the selection through a sort.

Comment: Added to [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/727443/return-to-keeping-existing-selections-when-changing-explorers-sort-column-or-order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my testing, beginning with Windows 7 (possibly Vista) the functionality you describe no longer exists.  I've tried a variety of settings in Windows Explorer and have found no workarounds.  **It looks like Microsoft has removed this and isn't bringing it back.**  The same "reset" behavior of the selected items happens even on Server 2012.

Unfortunately I think this new "feature" is by design.